# How to get the number of days on which i have data in prometheus using promq?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I need to know the number of days in prometheus for which i have data for the past 30 days.

My current approach is to fire 30 instant queries and seeing if i have data on each day.

Comment: What is the query that you currently have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should make the trick:

```
count_over_time((count_over_time(your_metric[1d]) > 0)[30d:1d])
```

It should return the number of days during the last 30 days when a time series with the name `your_metric` had at least a single sample.

The query uses [Prometheus subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/), which can substitute multiple calls to [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries) with a single call to this API.

If you need counting the number of days where at least a single sample exists across all the time series matching `your_metric`, then the following query can be used:

```
count_over_time((sum(count_over_time(your_metric[1d])) > 0)[30d:1d])
```